# How to Append Two Spark Dataframes with different columns in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have One Dataframe on which I am performing one UDF operation and then operation of UDF gives only one column in Dataframe.
How i can append it to previous Datafram.
Example:
Dataframe 1:
sr_no , name, salary

Dataframe 2: UDF is giving output as ABS(Salary) - only one column as output from UDF applied on Dataframe1

How i can have output dataframe as Dataframe1 + Dataframe2 in JAVA
i.e sr_no, name, salary, ABS(Salary) output

Comment: Do you need matching rows from 2 dfs or union?

Comment: no. 
UDF will give output with one column.
Need to append it with Dataframe on which this UDF is applied

Comment: Got the ans.
Just do it like this :  df= df.selectExpr("*","ABS(salary)");        This will give you output of udf with your entire dataframe. Else it will give only one column

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are searching for `.withColumn` method:

```scala
df1.withColumn("ABS(salary)", yourUdf.apply(col("salary")))
```

(Snippet requires to import static method `col` from `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`)

Comment: Got the ans.
Just do it like this :  df= df.selectExpr("*","ABS(salary)");        This will give you output of udf with your entire dataframe. Else it will give only one column

Answer (score 0):

Got the ans.
Just do it like this :  df= df.selectExpr("*","ABS(salary)");        This will give you output of udf with your entire dataframe. Else it will give only one column.